# How do you add an existing "microsoft account" to a azure subscription

Tags: azure, entra-id

We have an existing subscription that we'd like to give a user access to with their existing Microsoft Account. When we go into Azure subscription's access control and add the user, the only option we see "Azure AD user, group, or application" which creates a Azure AD user. We're wanting to add a Microsoft Account. We have an existing user that is added like this already, and they can switch between subscriptions easily in the top right Azure menu. We just can't figure out how to do it again.

Here is what it looks like with a MS Account added...

[image]

VS a AD user.

[image]

Comment: What is the reasoning for the down votes of the question??

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Microsoft Accounts as guest users, click on the "Add Guest User" button in the Azure AD user page.

Comment: Still shows up as "External Active Directory"

Comment: Yes, they will be external directory since they are guest users in your AD. It's expected.

Comment: Why do some show up as guest users and other as Microsoft account?

Comment: It still shows up as "External Azure Active Directory" instead of "Microsoft Account"

Comment: Are you sure the user you are adding are authenticating with a Microsoft Account rather than an another Active Directory? I see Guest users with 
newly-created outlook.com and gmail.com addresses appearing as "Microsoft account", but Guests users that are managed in another Azure AD appear as "External Azure Active Directory".

Comment: The SSO/AD/Microsoft Account system on Azure it totally broken. Inviting an existing Microsoft Account user just creates a new Active Directory for that domain and puts the user into that then fails to actually join them to the Directory they were invited to, just leaves them stuck in a AD on their own, and now when they login are forever prompted to choose between a "Personal" or an account setup by their "Work", neither of which have access to what they were invited for. Microsoft 